# Como inserir código HTML em um textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, textarea

Gostaria de saber como consigo colocar um código HTML em um `<textarea>`, pois tenho um `<textarea>` que recebe dados do DB dinamicamente por filtros de datas.
ex:

```
  <textarea maxlength="8000" rows="15" style="resize:none; width:100%">{{ctrl.VariavelDB}}</textarea>
```

utilizo AngularJS, o valor da variável seria assim:

```
ctrl.VariavelDB = "Lorem bla bla bla <b> negrito </b> bla bla bla <br> <h1> TESTE BAL BLA BLA </h1>"
```

Mas quando é inserido ele mostra o código, o que eu faço?

Comment: Da uma pesquisada em: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Comment: Você não vai conseguir fazer o código ser interpretado dentro do `textarea`, para isso use um [WYSIWYG editor](http://desenvolvimentoparaweb.com/javascript/melhores-editores-wysiwyg). Eu recomendo o [Quill](https://quilljs.com).

Comment: Por que um `textarea`? Se vai mostrar `html` deveria usar uma tag compatível, um `div` por exemplo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Com [`<textarea>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) não é possível. Acredito que esteja procurando um [`<div>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) [editável](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable):

```
<div contenteditable="true">
```

Veja o exemplo:

```html
<div contenteditable="true">Primeira linha.<br> Veja como o texto se adequá aqui. Também<br> é possível <strong>inserir quebras de linha</strong> ao final?
  <br>Funciona corretamente....
  <br>
  <br><span style="color: lightgreen">...ao invés de só texto você também aplica o seu estilo.</span>.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente fazemos isso com um elemento `<DIV>`.

É possivel fazer com outros elementos do HTML, como o `<P>` . Exemplo: https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp

Logo, o elemento pode receber um html, via javascript por exemplo, com jquery (por favor veja a notação semelhante para o angular):

```
$("#meuDiv").html("lorem <strong>ipsum</strong>.");
```